# VIM latex-suite inserts macro code instead of executing macros

Tags: vim, latex

I have a problem that's been bugging me for quite a while and that I can't find the solution to.

I want to use the feature where I can press `<C-j>` and the cursor moves to the next placeholder.
This works for regular files, but when I edit .tex files (i.e. latex-suite is enabled), this inserts:

```
\right=IMAP_Jumpfunc('', 0)
```

instead of actually jumping (which I presume is done by the above mapping somehow).

There's no problem with regular mappings (that I've made myself like so: `map rhs lhs`), but it doesn't work for any latex-suite macros. Other example: if I insert figure (via menu), it just inserts the following inside the text:

```
\right=Tex_DoEnvironment(``figure'')
```

Sorry I can't solve this problem myself, which is probably trivial for an experienced user. But I have no-one around to ask.

Comment: I think your question lost some context, make sure you enclose html-like notation with backticks.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean. What lost context? What's written in html-like notation in this case?

Comment: I added it for you.  You need to enclose `<things in angle brackets>` in backticks so that they do not get interpreted as HTML by the Markdown parser (and then not displayed since they are not on the white list).

Comment: Cheers! (...apparently I must write more than 8 characters in order to be allowed to comment by SO...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot the `<c-r>=` before the call to the function.

EDIT: I think I understand. Whem IMAPS is installed, it quickly parasites all our mappings. You will have to use IMAP() to define you own mappings. I [had to do it in my bracketing-system](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/map-tools/trunk/autoload/lh/brackets.vim#233) in order to be robust to IMAP/LaTeX-suite presence.

Comment: Yes, maybe so. There's certainly some entries in imaps.vim which contains `<c-r>=` 
Still, I didn't edit anything. If I understand correctly, latex-suite is supposed to call the IMAP_JumpForward macro but I don't know where it defines this mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Gah, I found the error!

I had defined a key mapping like so:

```
:imap <C-r> \right
```

(for adding to brackets in latex). This was then called by the pre-defined mappings ...

What a quagmire

Lesson taken: always comment-out entire or parts of the settings files, and then see if things start working.

Comment: Don't forget the : "never use :map, always prefer :noremap -- unless "recursive" mappings are required"

Comment: Right, I thought about that. But wouldn't the `:noremap` have to be put in the IMAP file, on the pre-defined mappings. Coz I tried putting it on my imap for `<C-r>` and that still messed up the mappings. I don't want to mess with the defaults...